# Can I download China Rising maps from xbox market place on a pc then send to a USB to use with my Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-4

Ive purchased china rising maps for xbox but I'm low on data and was wondering if I could download Battlefield 4: China Rising from a friend's PC and save it to an USB formatted for Xbox 360? I have enough data to play online for awhile but not enough to install the new china map pack.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to download Xbox 360 marketplace content on a PC and then transfer it to an Xbox 360. You might be able to download that content on a friend's Xbox 360 (using your own hard drive or a USB flash drive), but downloading it on a PC is almost certainly impossible.

Comment: Although, if I'm not mistaken, you can purchase items from a PC and have the Xbox 360 automatically download it remotely.

Comment: @Nolonar Yep, that's also true! Unfortunately that doesn't help the OP in his desire to avoid home data usage, though.